# generation of safe primes

Tags: encryption, openssl, primes

I need to generate a safe prime which has the form 2p + 1 where p is also prime of a certain
bit length (lets say 1024 bits). It is to be used in a DH key exchange.

I  believe openssl can do this via

openssl gendh 1024

however this return's a base64 pem format

```
-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
MIGHAoGBANzQ1j1z7RGB8XUagrGWK5a8AABecNrovcIgalv1hQdkna2PZorHtbOa
wYe1eDy1t/EztsM2Cncwvj5LBO3Zqsd5tneehKf8JoT35/q1ZznfLD8s/quBgrH8
es2xjSD/9syOMMiSv7/72GPJ8hzhLrbTgNlZ+kYBAPw/GcTlYjc7AgEC
-----END DH PARAMETERS-----
```

- How can I extract the safe prime number from this base64 pem?
- is it easier to generate my own safe prime with my own code?

how can i test that a prime is 'safe' and of a certain bit length.

Comment: Safe from what / for what purpose?  If you're doing a Diffie-Helman (DH) key exchange, why not use existing code?

Comment: I'm doing SPEKE which, uses DH and requires a safe prime to operate. So there is no existing code.

Comment: Are you able to use OpenSSL programatically instead of calling it on the command line?  What language are you using?

Comment: Not really, the langauge I'm writing in can't easily call C code, If that was the case I could easily copy the pieces i needed before it it's encoded into pem format.

Comment: In that case, can you just make a simple executable in C/C++ and call that from your application?  Seems like that would be easier than generating a PEM and then decoding it.  You're already making an external call to OpenSSL.

Comment: Consider using a standard Diffie-Hellman group.

Comment: This can now be done with e.g. `openssl prime -generate -safe -bits 1024`, which prints the prime number in base 10 directly to STDOUT - see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-prime.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@GregS has an approach that will probably work for you.  Based on what you have told me, I would just create a C binary and leverage the [`BN_generate_prime(...)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_generate_prime.html) function in OpenSSL.  That cuts out all of the intermediate parsing and despite adding a separate binary into the mix, it's probably easier than the road you are headed down.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the comments made by @Luke. However, if for some reason you *must* use openssl command lines there are a few options but they'll only get you so far. None of these will do any significant arithmetic for you; they won't retrieve (p-1)/2 and check it for primality.

You can use the `openssl dh` command and parse the output. Try it with and without the `-C` option to see which works better for you. Examples.

```
openssl gendh -out testdh.pem 1024
openssl dh -in testdh.pem -noout -C
openssl dh -in testdh.pem -noout
```

If you can handle or prefer binary then you can parse the binary output for the DER-encoded DH structure.

```
openssl dh -in testdh.pem -outform der -out testdh.der
```

Another option is to parse the output of the ans1parse command:

```
openssl asn1parse -in testdh.pem
```

Comment: To build on this, you can use the asn1parse command and take the "prim:" field and parse out the 256 character long ASCII-Hex number.  If you ensure that it's 256 ASCII characters, you know you have extracted a 1024-bit number.  Then you can just use the primality test of your choosing to test p and (p-1)/2 to make sure they are both prime.

Comment: how do we create testdh.dh ? gendh genereates a .pem file.

Comment: typo. Fixing, although you name the file anything you want.